# Using Postman, unable to reference CSV file for JavaScript test

Tags: postman, postman-collection-runner

I am using a REST API with a POST request.  I have created a CSV file to load in various inputs and using the Collection Runner to submit my requests and run the associated JavaScript Tests iteratively.  I am trying to figure out how I can also have an entry in each row of the CSV to reference for my JavaScript Test in order to make the JavaScript dynamic.  I've searched the Postman documentation and forums, as well as Google and Stack Overflow, but I haven't found anything that works.  Here is a basic example of what I'm trying to accomplish.

---

Let's say I have a basic adding API.  Here is my Request:

```
{
    "Numbers": {
        "Value_1": {{val1}},
        "Value_2": {{val2}},
            }
}
```

The CSV file is as follows:

```
val1,val2,sum
1,1,2
2,2,4
3,3,6
```

For this example, lets assume that the API returns a response that includes the sum of val1 and val2; something like this:

```
{
    "Numbers": {{sum}},
}
```

I am able to load val1 and val2 into my request and iterate through the request for each row, but I am having trouble incorporating the sum values (from the same CSV) into the JavaScript Test.

I am trying to do something like the test below where I can reference the sum value from my spreadsheet, but Postman doesn't like my syntax.

```
pm.test("Adding machine", function () {   
var jsonData = pm.response.json();
pm.expect(jsonData.Numbers === {{sum}});
});
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?  Is this even possible to do?

Comment: Have you looked at using the pm.iterationData() function to get those values and assert against them in your test? https://www.getpostman.com/docs/v6/postman/scripts/postman_sandbox_api_reference

Comment: Thanks Danny.  This worked for me.  I ended up doing something like this:

_____________________________________________________________


   var sumVal = pm.iterationData.get("sum");
   var data = JSON.parse(responseBody);
   tests["Adding machin"] = data.Numbers === sumVal;

Comment: Cool, I've added a test that might work as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `pm.iterationData().get('var_name')` function and create a check like this?

```
pm.test("Sums are correctly calculated", () => {
    pm.expect(pm.response.json().Numbers).to.equal(pm.iterationData.get('sum'))
})
```